# make particular word (string) in caps with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a word "Real" in the website I don't want to search it page by page and make it caps.

I am trying to make "Real" word in caps through jquery and I am using the below code:

```
$('jqueryselector').val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
<html> code Real Change Fellowship
```

The above code is making whole text in caps and i just want to make "Real" word in caps.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In case your code above is working (`.val()`, really?), in order to uppercase just "real" and not the whole string, you'd need to do a string replace:

```
$(this).val().replace(/real/gi, 'REAL');
```

As pointed out by Jaromanda in comments, the actual expression could be improved upon, pending your exact requirements, but this would be the general idea.

There are conceptual issues with this, however, if you're doing this because "Real" is an abbreviation. You will never be able to definitely distinguish the abbreviation from all uses of the English word "real". If at all an option, I would definitely consider getting the source content right rather than trying to patch it up post hoc. Most IDE's should come with a "search and replace in all files" functionality.

Comment: But what if other word contains substring `real` ? `unreal, realistic, etc...`

Comment: I'd use `\breal\b/gmi` ... or `\bReal\b/gm` to answer the specific question of changing Real to REAL if only Real should be changed

Answer (score 0):

The following will change the 'Real' word alone to 'REAL'

```
 $('jqueryselector').val($(this).val().replace(\bReal\b/gm, 'REAL'));
```